# How to add CSS style on a div under a PHP tag

Tags: php, css

[image]Basically,I have a div under a php tag. I have already tried adding a style for it but none of it was working. I just need to apply a margin right. maybe my code was incorrect. some help? here is the jsfiddle link.

CSS:

```
.result_text{
    margin-right: 25%;: 
}
.result_text a{
    margin-right: 25%;
}
```

PHP:

```
 <?php
    echo "<div class='result_text'> <a href='#' > This is a sample text  </a> </div>" ;
 ?>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cpj9s2p5/

Comment: jsfiddle doesn't parse php tags. this code is fine, run in from a server that actually has php and you'll be fine..

Comment: JS Fiddle will not parse PHP for you. Also, the [CSS is working](https://jsfiddle.net/cpj9s2p5/1/).

Comment: You missed end double quote and a semi colon in your echo

Comment: i already did :( but still not working

Comment: HTML that is put out by php does not react differently to css formatting than any other html in your source. Basically a php tag is not a tag in the html sense of the word it's a small program that happens to be in the same file your html is in. So where ever the reason for your CSS problem might be rooted. PHP is not it.

Comment: are you trying to run this off your own PC and as `.php` or as `.html`. If on your PC, did you install PHP and a webserver? If so, accessing as what, `http://localhost/file.php` or as `c:///file.php`? Two different animals here.

Comment: what you wrote above is already correct and should work (or at least the edited version). Are you opening it via a server (localhost)? And is the CSS in the header or referenced properly?

Comment: `margin-right: 25%;:` <<< is that colon `:` actually part of your code here? If it is, remove it. Plus, if you have any other rules somewhere and want to override it, add `!important` to it.

Comment: ok thanks for your help. you don't have to be so rude

Comment: The fiddle works  and all you have to do is to check if you have php on your webserver. And the file must be in .php format and not .html since you are using php tags

Comment: LOL, my stupid mistake. it was margin-left not margin right . anyway thanks for the help everyone

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
<?php
echo "<div class='result_text' style='margin-right: 20px;'> <a href='#' > This is a sample text</a></div>";
?>
```

Comment: exactly is good but maybe he needs add !important bacause i f he have more styles maybe does not work, i guess

Comment: `inline css` gets the highest priority.

Comment: `!important` actually has higher priority.

Comment: yea, the text under the anchor tag works fine. but the CSS isn't working. i already tried your suggestion :( why

Comment: @gracia, do you have any other element beside this ? How would you know that it's working ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo "<div class='result_text'>"." <a href='#' >"." This is a sample text"." </a>"." </div>" ; ?>
```

Read more about concat.

Comment: And what difference does that make?

Comment: I noticed you didnt have values on your other css attributes.  Give them some values then at the end put semicolon

Comment: I'm not the OP, I was just questioning why you said they need to break up the string and concatenate it when a single string will do.

Comment: Sorry i missed the whole code because im on mobile.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php
echo "<div class='result_text' style='margin-right: 20px !important;'> <a href='#' > This is a sample text  </a> </div>" ;


?>
```

dont forget !important in your style

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your fiddle is that you don't have PHP running, it is just HTML and `<?php echo "<div class='result_text'>` is being commented out. If you had PHP running on a server this code should work as intended.